# Brown's theorem on Manifolds and Milnor's notation for a peculiar mapping

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I am reading *Milnor's Topology from a Differentiable Viewpoint*, which is very nice. I am reading about regular points versus critical points, etc. I ran across some notation that I was not very clear about. On page 11, as part of the proof of Brown's theorem, he references a particular operator, and I was not clear on what the notation was actually referring to. if anyone can explain, it would really help.

So he is talking about an manifold $M \subset R^k$,$N \subset R^m$ and a linear map $L: R^k \rightarrow R^{m-n}$ that is nonsingular on the subspace $\mathfrak{R} \subset TM_x \subset R^k$.

This is where it gets confusing for me:

Now define
$$
F: M \rightarrow N \times R^{m-n}
$$

by $F(\xi) = (f(\xi), L(\xi))$ The derivative $dF_x$ is clearly given by the formula

$$
dF_x = (df_x(\nu), L(\nu))
$$

I was trying to understand what this mapping $F: M \rightarrow N \times R^{m-n}$ means, and this reference to $F(\xi) = (f(\xi), L(\xi))$. Is $F$ the cartesian product of all points in N with all vectors in $R^{m-n}$? What would be the use of that? Also, this $F(\xi)$ notation, what does it mean that I have $(f(\xi), L(\xi))$. Like what does that tuple represent, if both of those are mappings to different sized spaces?

So I think I am missing what the intent of the notation is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's the cartesian product. And the use is, very likely, that, for the combined map, dimension counting is easy and the implicit or inverse function theorem can be applied.